# Android hide list item and remove space ( release space )

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-adapter

I have a list view with headers. In my list view I have two header and under each header I have items. What I want to do is to hide items when user clicked on header. And on click that header again the items will be visible. I have an interface and then model classes which implements this interface for both header and data. I have hide the items but unable to hide space. Here is my code of onListItemClick().

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    UserAddress userAddress = (UserAddress) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (userAddress instanceof LocationHeader) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++) {
                            View listItemView = getListView().getChildAt(i);
                            if (listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_header) != null) {

                            } else {

                                if (listItemView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    listItemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                } else {
                                    listItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                     listItemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

I have also tried to get the main layout of my adapter items and hide it. But it also worked the same way. Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646147/hide-row-from-listview-without-taking-up-space) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917049/android-set-view-gone-does-not-release-space-in-listview/7928923#7928923) ,but same result. I do not want to remove items , and refill them again. Is there any way around? or I have to do this remove and add approach ? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't use ExpandableListView? it just for it kind list.

Comment: Ok. That's a good suggestion. But I tried expendable first. But my case is too complex for it. Basically I am doing google places search with a specific text. Have to call two places api's for this work. So expendable wont worked for me.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="fill_parent"  may  fixed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646147/hide-row-from-listview-without-taking-up-space?lq=1