# How to totally hidden element stacked on a CardView?

Tags: android, layout

I have a `CardView` on `list_song.xml` file such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mxhbg"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtitemsong"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listsongbg"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmusic"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listsongbg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_music" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsongname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgmusic"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Which I bind using a `BaseAdapter` on my `Activity`:

```
public class PlaylistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_song, parent, false);

        RelativeLayout txtitemsong = view.findViewById(R.id.txtitemsong);
        if (position < 2 || position > 5) {
            txtitemsong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Due to some limits (in this case 2/5 as example), I'd like to totally hide some `txtitemsong` items, which are stacked vertically.

But once I hide it with `txtitemsong.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, it seems the margin of each txtitemsong is kept (so lots of space above/below the showed items).

How can I hide a whole `txtitemsong` stacked item?

I could set `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"` on `CardView`, but seems it has no effect. The same `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"` on `txtitemsong` directly, nothing change.

Here's the original view:

[image]

And that's the view with `txtItemSong.setVisibility(View.GONE)` hiding the first 2 items and the last ones:

[image]

How you can see, there are margin/padding on the top part, before the list of items starts.

If I hide CardView and I do:

```
if (position < 2 || position > 5) {
    txtItemSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = txtItemSong.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 0;
    txtItemSong.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

here's the result (even weird):

[image]

Comment: can you explain your problem with a screenshot of what currently happening and what is expected?

Comment: @Maveňツ added screenshots and what is expected, hope it helps?

Comment: @Maveňツ tried (update my question with the details). It seems even weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code in which we filtered the songList before iterate it

```
public class PlaylistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public PlaylistAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = filterItems(items);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> filterItems(ArrayList<String> originalItems) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= 5 && i < originalItems.size(); i++) {
            filteredItems.add(originalItems.get(i));
        }
        return filteredItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_song, parent, false);

        CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

        //use this incase filterItems doesn't works
        // if (position < 2 || position > 5) {
        //     cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //     cardView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //     cardView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        // }

        return view;
    }
}
```

A new method called filterItems() which takes original list of items and returns a filtered list containing item from indexs 2 to 5 (inclusive).

Ref link for more suggestions

[Android set View.GONE does not "release" space in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917049/android-set-view-gone-does-not-release-space-in-listview)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why it says `Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling` on `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_song, parent, false);`? Somethings I can fix?

Comment: @markzzz try this  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_list_row, parent, false);