# How can I add a different button on Toolbar in Different Activity?

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

Here's my `activity_main.xml`, which have a basic `Toolbar` and two `Button`s on the right (and as well a `NavigationView`):

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mxhbg"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mxhbg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_shuffle">

                    </Button>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnRescanSongs"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync">

                    </Button>
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </LinearLayout>

            // other stuff
            
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I set it on MainActivity this way:

```java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Now, on another Activity (SyncActivity), I'd like to display the same `Toolbar` but with different icons on the right.

What's the correct way to do this?

Doing this on `activity_sync.xml`:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mxhbg"
        tools:context=".SyncActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mxhbg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnRescanSongs"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync">

                    </Button>
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/log"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and on SyncActivity:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Sync");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

it adds a new `Toolbar`, below the main one.

Also: why the icons on main `Toolbar` are not showed on other Activity? Seems it hides them? Why?

Comment: could you please share your themes.xml file? thanks

Comment: @Lino I don't have any themes.xml?

Comment: markzzz use menu xml as mentioned by @madlymad

Comment: @Maveňツ tried, but can't make it working.

Comment: @markzzz have you removed buttons from toolbar and added menu XML ,  onCreateOptionsMenu  and onOptionsItemSelected ?

Comment: @Maveňツ what a stupid I am, got casually the problem now, did "getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);" on both activities. Now doing main_menu and sync_menu works. Thanks for trigger me :)

Comment: @Maveňツ since your seems addicted, maybe can you also help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159434/how-to-totally-hidden-element-stacked-on-a-cardview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all the toolbar buttons from the layout xml and move them to menu xml like that.

File: `res/menu/yourmenuname.xml`

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_random"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
        android:title="@string/menu_rescan_songs"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_rescan_songs"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
        android:title="@string/menu_rescan_songs"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Note that you also have to provide a title and not only the icon you can use the showAsAction with `always` to display always the icon or `ifRoom` or `ifRoom|withText`  just experiment what likes you most.

Then in each of your activities you override this function to load your menu. Pay attention to `yourmenuname` that will be different in each one of the activities.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenuname,menu);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And to handle the menu actions use:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_random:
            doSomethingElse();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_rescan_songs:
            doSomething();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In the second activity use the different menu with the different options and do the handling and creation in a similar way.

There are a lot of stuff you can do with the menus, adding here some links that may help you keep reading on them:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource
- https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar
- https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#options-menu

Comment: But I want them buttons on a the toolbar, top/right. Isn't a menu in Android display different and on different zone? Also, what do you mean with "In the second activity use the different menu"? What is the "different menu"?

Comment: The `MainActivity` and the `SyncActivity` you will create 2 menus one for each, that will include the icons. Its called menu but if you use it with always its displayed like image button. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#options-menu the actionbar/toolbar have quite strict design guidelines if you don't want this UI then you maybe have to build something custom by yourself and not use the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same Toolbar in multiple screens, include it in BaseActivity. This activity should include all common UIs of your application.

Then you have to extend MainActivity/SyncActivity from BaseActivity

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    var  baseLayoutBinding : ActivityBaseBinding? = null

    override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) {
       baseLayoutBinding = ActivityBaseBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
    layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, baseLayoutBinding?.mainContainer, true)
    
       super.setContentView(baseLayoutBinding?.root)
   }

   protected fun setUpToolbar(var title : String?, var rightDrawable : Int ) {  }

}


class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
       setUpToolbar(“Title1” , R.drawable.main_activity_drawable) 
}

class SyncActivity : BaseActivity() {   
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.sync_activity)
    setUpToolbar(“Title2” , R.drawable.sync_activity_drawable) 
}
```